# Vue 3 computed object in template throws error

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm trying to convert my options based components to use the composition API as I have a bunch of methods I need in multiple components.
One of these methods looks like this:
`const currentTile = computed((): Tile => getTileAt(mapStore.getState().currentCoordinates));`

This and the other methods are namespaced to an object called `map` in my `setup()` method:
`const map = useMap();`

This is also returned, but when I'm trying to use it in the templateas a prop for another component (`:tile="map.currentTile"`), I get the following runtime error:

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "tile". Expected Tile, got Object

What am I doing wrong here? The documentation says that computed infers the return type: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-computed

EDIT: Seems I need to use `.value` in the template as well. So, updated question, is there a way to omit this in the template?

EDIT2: if I again wrap the return from the composition function in `reactive` it works without `.value`. But this seems like an overly bloated syntax, especially considering the `mapStore.getState()` is already a reactive value.

EDIT3: adding code snippet:

```js
const { computed, createApp, defineComponent, reactive, readonly } = Vue;

class Clazz {
  _str = '';
  _int = 0;
  constructor(str: string) {
    this._str = str;
  }
  get str(): string {
    return this._str;
  }
  get int(): number {
    return this._int;
  }
  increment(): void {
    this._int++;
  }
}
interface Test {
  clazz: Clazz;
}
class TestStore {
  state: Test;
  constructor() {
    this.state = reactive({
            clazz: new Clazz('test'),
        });
    }
    getState(): Test {
        return readonly(this.state);
    }
  increment(): void {
    this.state.clazz.increment();
  }
}
const testStore = new TestStore();

function useStore() {
  const clazz = computed((): Clazz => testStore.getState().clazz);
  return {
    clazz,
  };
}

const CounterComponent = defineComponent({
    name: 'CounterComponent',
  props: {
    clazz: {
            type: Clazz,
            required: true,
        },
  },
  setup() {
    function increment() {
      testStore.increment();
    }
    return {
      increment,
    };
  },
  template: '<button @click="increment">Clicks: {{ clazz.int }}</button> {{clazz.str}}',
});

const TestComponent = defineComponent({
    name: 'TestComponent',
  components: {
    CounterComponent,
  },
    setup() {
        const store = useStore();
    return {
      store,
    };
  },
  template: '<counter-component :clazz="store.clazz"></counter-component>',
});
createApp(TestComponent).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Props need a constructor to check the type of your object. Passing just `{ title: 'something' }` as a prop isn't a correct *Title*; it's an *Object*. If you want a *Title*, use a class with a constructor.

Comment: Tile is a real class with a constructor. I found out the error comes from the wrapper object which Vue3 adds when using computed: Ref<Tile> As can be seen here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-refs

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @str  was a bit of a hassle, as the SO snippet tool does have some limitations and even the minimal example was quite complex